# AngularJS ng-repeat-start with limitTo doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of several objects and at the beginning I want to load just some of them. I took a look at the statement `ng-repeat`, but I need to have a structure like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-hidden">
       <thead>
           <tr>
           ...
           </tr>
       </thead>

       <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat-start="object in objects | filter:query | orderBy:predicate:reverse"  ng-init="isCollapsed=true">   
          ...
         </tr>
         <tr ng-repeat-end class="more">
          ...
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

I tried to apply the statement limitTo inside `ng-repeat-start`, in this way:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="object in objects | filter:query | orderBy:predicate:reverse| limitTo: limit"  ng-init="isCollapsed=true">
```

and on controller I wrote:

```
 $scope.limit = 10;

    $scope.incrementLimit = function () {
        $scope.limit += 10;
    };
```

The function `incrementLimit` is called by a click on hyperlink

```
 <a href ng-click="incrementLimit()">more</a>
```

The list of objects is instantiated and filled (with all the elements) when the page loads.

With my approach at the beginnig are loaded and showed first 10 elements correctly, and when I click on "more" the variable `$scope.limit`is incremented, but on the page nothing happens. Anyone can explain me why?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hejizeluco/1/edit?html,js,output can you check the fidde here working fine

Comment: @EdgarZakaryan here working two-way binding, direct call `$scope.$apply()` not needed

Comment: @EdgarZakaryan calling `$scope.$apply()` inside the function `incrementLimit()` I have this type of exception: "**Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress**"

Comment: @FabrizioMorello, can you provide jsfiddle of plunker with problem? code seems work

Comment: @FabrizioMorello take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

`limitTo` is working fine inside `ng-repeat-start`

Take a look at this

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.limit = 1;

    $scope.incrementLimit = function () {
        $scope.limit += 1;
    };
    
    $scope.data = [{
        title: 'Foo',
        text: 'Lorem'
    }, {
        title: 'Bar',
        text: 'Iste'
    }, {
        title: 'Jon',
        text: 'Fat'
    }, {
        title: 'Los',
        text: 'Ice'
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller">
    <table border="2" class="table table-hover table-hidden">
        <thead>
            <tr>...</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat-start="object in data | filter:query | orderBy:predicate:reverse| limitTo: limit" ng-init="isCollapsed=true" ng-bind="object.title">...</tr>
            <tr ng-repeat-end class="more">...</tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a href="#" ng-click="incrementLimit()">more</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code and fiddle it is working fine

```
     <body ng-controller="myController">
  <button ng-click="incrementLimit()" >increment</button> <br/>
            <table class="table table-hover table-hidden">
                <thead>
                    <tr clospan="3">
                        Head
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat-start="friend in objects|limitTo: limit"  ng-init="isCollapsed=true">
                        <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
                        <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr ng-repeat-end class="more">
                        <td colspan="3">Footer</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </table>
    </body>
```

js code

```
app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
$scope.objects =
    [{
        name: 'John',
        phone: '555-1212',
        age: 10
    }, {
        name: 'Mary',
        phone: '555-9876',
        age: 19
    }, {
        name: 'Mike',
        phone: '555-4321',
        age: 21
    }, {
        name: 'Adam',
        phone: '555-5678',
        age: 35
    }, {
        name: 'Julie',
        phone: '555-8765',
        age: 29
    }];
   $scope.limit = 2;

$scope.incrementLimit = function () {
    $scope.limit += 1;
};
});
```

Fiddle http://jsbin.com/hoguxexuli/1/edit

Comment: you have wrong markup, inside `tr` should be `td` tag

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Basically I put the hyperlink in a different div, so the controller and the `$scope` were also different. It was a stupid carelessness.